# Query juntando duas tabelas e preenchendo campos de forma condicional

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, select

Sou iniciante em SQL e gostaria de saber se poderiam me ajudar com uma questão.

Tenho duas tabelas, uma se chama **Cadastro_Func** e a outra **CadastroFocal**.

A 'Cadastro_Func' possui as colunas:

- 'Apelido'
- 'Nome'
- 'Cargo'

A 'Cadastro_Focal' possui as colunas:

- 'Comunidade'
- 'Apelido'
- 'PontoFocal'

Gostaria de selecionar o campo 'PontoFocal' da tabela 'Cadastro_Focal' e substituir o campo 'Apelido' pelo respectivo nome da tabela 'Cadastro_Func', além da 'Comunidade'.

Exemplo:

**Cadastro_Func**:

- Apelido: **Ale**
- Nome: **Alessandro**
- Cargo: **Gestor**

**Cadastro_Focal**:

- Comunidade: **Logistica**
- Apelido: **Ale**
- PontoFocal: **Rubens**

**Resultado**:

- Comunidade: **Logistica**
- Nome: **Alessandro**
- PontoFocal: **Rubens**

Mas a real dificuldade é juntar a esta mesma seleção uma qualificação por cargo, onde:

- Os nomes cujo 'Cargo' seja "Gestor" ficassem separados na coluna 'NomeGestor';
- Os nomes cujo 'Cargo' seja "Coordenador" ficassem separados na coluna 'NomeCoordenador'.

Seria algo como:

**Cadastro_Func**:
**Apelido - Nome - Cargo**
Ale - Alessandro - Gestor
Ge - Jorge - Coordenador
Li - Linda - Gestor

**Cadastro_Focal**:
**Comunidade - Apelido - Nome**
Logistica - Ale - Rubens
Produção - Ge - Luna
P&D - Li - José

**Saída**:
**Comunidade - NomeGestor  - NomeCoordenador - PontoFocal**
Logistica - Alessandro - xxxx - Rubens
Produção - xxxx - Jorge - Luna
P&D - Linda - xxxxx - José

Desde já obrigado, é minha primeira pergunta por aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Se a versão do seu SQL Server for **anterior à 2012**, você pode usar a expressão [CASE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) para resolver o seu problema:

```
SELECT
  fo.Comunidade,
  NomeGestor = CASE fu.Cargo WHEN 'Gestor' THEN fu.Nome ELSE NULL END,
  NomeCoordenador = CASE fu.Cargo WHEN 'Coordenador' THEN fu.Nome ELSE NULL END,
  fo.PontoFocal
FROM
  Cadastro_Func AS fu
  INNER JOIN Cadastro_Focal AS fo ON fo.Apelido = fu.Apelido
ORDER BY
  fo.Comunidade
```

Mas se a versão do seu SQL Server for **maior ou igual à 2012**, você pode usar a função [IIF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql):

```
SELECT
  fo.Comunidade,
  IIF(fu.Cargo = 'Gestor', fu.Nome, NULL) AS NomeGestor,
  IIF(fu.Cargo = 'Coordenador', fu.Nome, NULL) AS NomeCoordenador,
  fo.PontoFocal
FROM
  Cadastro_Func AS fu
  INNER JOIN Cadastro_Focal AS fo ON fo.Apelido = fu.Apelido
ORDER BY
  fo.Comunidade
```