# Selecionar da coluna B caso campo selecionado na coluna A seja null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Em uma consulta *SQL* estava tentando elaborar um meio de selecionar um valor de outra coluna **B** caso o valor selecionado da coluna **A** seja nulo. A principio fiz a seguinte query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(max(convert(smalldatetime,DEP.DATAENTRADA,100)),null), DEP.DATANASCIMENTO,100) as UltimoDependente
    from DEPENDENTES DEP
        join FUNCIONARIOS FUNC  on FUNC.FILIAL=DEP.FILIAL and FUNC.MATRICULA=DEP.MATRICULA and FUNC.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
     where FUNC.MATRICULA = '10'
       and FUNC.FILIAL = '01'
       and DEP.R_E_C_D_E_L_=0
```

E a query não funciona. Há algum meio de realizar isso?

Comment: Você quer retornar o maior valor do campo `DEP.DATAENTRADA`, e se esse campo for nulo você quer retornar o valor do campo `DEP.DATANASCIMENTO`, é isso? Eles têm tipos diferentes?

Comment: não. eu quero retornar a ultima data. Se o campo DATAENTRADA não for nulo, eu utilizo ele para fazer a consulta. Agora se o campo não tiver uma data cadastrada, ou seja, for nulo, eu quero usar o campo DATANASCIMENTO

Comment: Já tentou usar o Coalesce sozinho? Assim: SELECT COALESCE(SUA_DATA_ENTRADA, DATANASCIMENTO)

Comment: Qual o erro que dá?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

```sql
select
  COALESCE(DEP.DATAENTRADA, DEP.DATANASCIMENTO) as UltimoDependente
from
  DEPENDENTES DEP
  join FUNCIONARIOS FUNC on FUNC.FILIAL = DEP.FILIAL
  and FUNC.MATRICULA = DEP.MATRICULA
  and FUNC.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '
where
  FUNC.MATRICULA = '10'
  and FUNC.FILIAL = '01'
  and DEP.R_E_C_D_E_L_ = 0
```

A função `COALESCE` retorna o primeiro argumento que não seja nulo, então, se o valor do campo `DEP.DATAENTRADA` não for nulo, ele será retornado, se for nulo, e o valor do campo `DEP.DATANASCIMENTO` não for nulo, o segundo será retornado. Se os dois forem nulos o retorno desse campo será `NULL`.

Referência:

> [COALESCE (Transact-SQL) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Pedro... Fiz uma pequena alteração na linha `COALESCE(isnull(max(convert(smalldatetime,SRB.RB_DTENTRA,100)),''), isnull(max(convert(smalldatetime,SRB.RB_DTNASC,100)),'')) as UltimoDependente` para trabalhar com data. Entretanto, por padrão o SQL Server define a data 01-01-1900 para campos `datetime` nulos. Dessa maneira como o campo da primeira coluna (DATAENTREGA) é nulo, sempre será retornado essa data. Por causa disso que eu usei o `MAX()`, para pegar o maior valor. entretanto não funcionou

Comment: Acho que você está confundindo, se você atribuir o valor `NULL` ao campo ele ficará nulo, independente do tipo (desde que ele permita nulos, é claro). Eu acabei de fazer um teste, criei uma tabela de testes com um campo id, outro do tipo `smalldatetime`, outro `datetime` e outro `datetime2`, e todos ficaram com valor nulo ao criar um novo registro e não informar nada nesses campos.

Comment: Mas, se o seu campo data pode ter o valor `01-01-1900` para demonstrar que não tem valor, você poderia usar a expressão `CASE` ou a função `IIF` (caso a versão do seu SQL Server seja maior ou igual a 2012): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/336945/86952, algo como: COALESCE( IIF(DEP.DATAENTRADA = '01-01-1900', NULL, DEP.DATAENTRADA) , DEP.DATANASCIMENTO)

Comment: Confundi mesmo Pedro kkk, no caso, se o campo estiver vazio e usar o `convert` para `datetime`, por padrão o SQL usa a data 1990-01-01

Comment: Tranquilo, acontece! :) Mas, se a resposta tiver resolvido a dúvida original, marque ela como aceita (clicando no "sinal de visto", ✓, logo abaixo da seta para baixo), por favor, para ajudar outras pessoas que possam ter a mesma dúvida. Veja essas páginas: [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), e [Por que é importante votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).